# Save two array data in database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a user input that is in array.

Sample request:

```
{
    "request": {
        "phone_number": [ "0321553678", "0321444" ],
        "amount": [ "10", "20" ]
    }
}
```

I need to save this in the database. The first `phone_number` (0321553678) in the array goes together with the first `amount` (10) in the amount array and so on.

I have tried looping as below but I am not sure how to loop with both inputs. It does not work this way.

```
$data = request(['amount', 'phone_number');

foreach($data as $input) 
{
    Transaction::create([
        'amount' => $input->amount,
        'phone_number' => $input->phone_number,
    ]);
```

Both `amount` and `phone_number` come as arrays with their indexes corresponding.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple PHP you have to use "key" part of the foreach loop

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {}
```

you will get index in the array in `$key` variable for current `$value`.

```
$array = ['a','b','c'];
$array2 = [10, 20, 30];

foreach($array as $index => $char) {
  echo $char + " => " + $array2[$index] // => "a => 10"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave json data here, I would do something like this.

```
$data = json_decode('{"request":{"phone_number":["0321553678","0321444"],"amount":["10","20"]}}');

$phoneNumbers = $data->request->phone_number;
$amount = $data->request->amount;

$map = array_combine($phoneNumbers, $amount);

foreach ($map as $phoneNumber => $amount) {
    Transaction::create([
        'amount' => $amount,
        'phone_number' => $phoneNumber
    ]);
}
```

There are probably more efficient ways to do it, or with less lines of code, but my initial instinct is to put the two arrays into variables, and make each one a corresponding key/value array (using `array_combine`) because it's readable and understandable.

Hope that helps.

Edit:  I'm not sure what the `Transaction` class is, but since it's static `create` method seems to take an array, it's likely that you could pass the entire 'dataset' to it.  The reason I bring this up is because if it, as the name indicates, creates a transaction, you will probably want to save "all or none", and have the transaction rollback if any of the values are incorrect/fail some kind of internal validation, etc.  Something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to index the information within the database by each field you could

```
$db->bind('data',serialize($data));
$db->query('insert into ...');
```

Otherwise you can iterate through the array and put it in the correct order.

```
// parse 
$requests = array();
foreach($data as $value_1) {
 foreach($value as $value_2) {
  $requests[] = ... 
  )
 }
}
```

Then insert the requests.

You could also consider structuring your data differently:

```
{
 "request":
 [
  {"phone_number":"0321553678","amount":"10"},
  {"phone_number":"0321444","amount":"20"}
 ]
}
```

Sorry, being abruptly interrupted... I hope that helps.